# My computer keeps restart when accept Skype call

Tags: windows-xp, skype

I'm using latest Skype version (4.2) on Windows XP SP3

My computer keeps restart when I click "Accept" button on Skype call

Windows Update is running and I've already installed all updates

What's wrong with my computer? How to fix it?

**EDIT:** I only see this error in Event Viewer

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   System Error
Event Category: (102)
Event ID:   1003
Date:       3/2/2010
Time:       3:47:50 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   TUANANH
Description:
Error code 1000000a, parameter1 ffffff94, parameter2 0000001c, parameter3 00000000, parameter4 80537bf1.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: 53 79 73 74 65 6d 20 45   System E
0008: 72 72 6f 72 20 20 45 72   rror  Er
0010: 72 6f 72 20 63 6f 64 65   ror code
0018: 20 31 30 30 30 30 30 30    1000000
0020: 61 20 20 50 61 72 61 6d   a  Param
0028: 65 74 65 72 73 20 66 66   eters ff
0030: 66 66 66 66 39 34 2c 20   ffff94, 
0038: 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 63   0000001c
0040: 2c 20 30 30 30 30 30 30   , 000000
0048: 30 30 2c 20 38 30 35 33   00, 8053
0050: 37 62 66 31               7bf1
```

Comment: Is there anything in the event log that would point to a problem? My gut would say it's a bad audio driver maybe.

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: It is a BSOD-Restart, or does windows shutdown normally?
Can you give more details?

Comment: Without any notice. Just restart like you press `Reset` button on your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My soundcard is working fine. Tested with dxdiag tool

I removed Souncard driver, clean registry and installed the newest driver from mainboard's homepage

Use default soundcard configuration and open Skype. It works fine

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to play other sounds? Do you hear any audio (windows system sounds, or audio from internet movies?)

Are you able to record sounds e.g. using windows sound recorder?

The restart seems to be caused by BSOD and BSOD is most likely caused by some issue with the audio driver - either the playback part, or the recording part.

The event viewer entry you have provided unfortunately does not contain enough information to identify the driver.

Comment: Yes, I cannot see any `unregconized driver` in Device Manager. Windows Sound Recorder working fine. And I don't see any Error Event about Sound related in Event Viewer

Answer (score 1):

Setup a virtual machine (with VMware player e.g.) and install windows inside or whatever. Install skype and try to be called - if it works it means that it might be that your hardware is screwed (audio card or motherboard).

Comment: Yes, I will try